# Profile picture not showing android chat app.Java

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm building an android chat application and I'm using the Picasso picture cache dependency. When I open my chat application and go to my settings, I can't see my profile picture. Even after changing it, it still remains invisible but the new profile picture is stored in my Firebase database alright.

```
( implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828')
```

This is my Java code:

```
package com.nalexander240.michat;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;
import com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;
import com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropImage;
import com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropImageView;

import de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView;

public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private CircleImageView settingsDisplayProfileImage;
    private TextView settingsDisplayName,settingsDisplayStatus;
    private Button settingsChangeProfileImageButton,settingsChangeStatusButton;

    final static int galleryPick=1;
    private StorageReference storeProfileImagestorageRef;

    private DatabaseReference getUserDataReference;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);

        mAuth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        String onlineUserID=mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
        getUserDataReference= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(onlineUserID);
        storeProfileImagestorageRef=FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("Profile_Images");

        settingsDisplayProfileImage=(CircleImageView) findViewById(R.id.profileImage);
        settingsDisplayName=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.settingsUsername);
        settingsDisplayStatus=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.settingsUserStatus);
        settingsChangeProfileImageButton=(Button) findViewById(R.id.settingsChangeProfileImageButton);
        settingsChangeStatusButton=(Button) findViewById(R.id.settingsChangeProfileStatusButton);

        getUserDataReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
            {
                String name=dataSnapshot.child("Username").getValue().toString();
                String status=dataSnapshot.child("UserStatus").getValue().toString();
                String image=dataSnapshot.child("UserImage").getValue().toString();
                String thumbImage=dataSnapshot.child("userThumbImage").getValue().toString();

                settingsDisplayName.setText(name);
                settingsDisplayStatus.setText(status);
                Picasso.get().load(image).into(settingsDisplayProfileImage);




            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

        settingsChangeProfileImageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent galleryIntent=new Intent();
                galleryIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(galleryIntent,galleryPick);
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode==galleryPick && resultCode==RESULT_OK && data!=null){
            Uri ImageUri=data.getData();

            // start picker to get image for cropping and then use the image in cropping activity
            CropImage.activity()
                    .setGuidelines(CropImageView.Guidelines.ON)
                    .setAspectRatio(1,1)
                    .start(this);

        }
        if (requestCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE)
        {
            CropImage.ActivityResult result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data);

            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

                Uri resultUri = result.getUri();

                String userID=mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
                StorageReference filePath=storeProfileImagestorageRef.child(userID + ".jpg");

                filePath.putFile(resultUri).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()){
                            Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this,
                                    "Saving your profile image online...",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                            String downloadUrl=task.getResult().getStorage().getDownloadUrl().toString();

                            getUserDataReference.child("UserImage").setValue(downloadUrl)
                                    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>()
                                    {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task)
                                        {
                                            Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this,
                                                    "Profile image uploaded successfully.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                        }
                                    });
                        }
                        else {

                            Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this,
                                    "Error occurred while uploading profile pic,try again.",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
            else if (resultCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_RESULT_ERROR_CODE) {
                Exception error = result.getError();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Your question is currently not very clear. Please try to solve the issue first by yourself, e. g. by debugging your application and stepping through the code. If you are still facing the issue afterwards, edit your question and include what you've tried to solve the issue.Also, please reduce your code to a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and have a look at [this help article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: String.   image=dataSnapshot.child("UserImage").getValue().toString();                             the above line of code is supposed to take a snapshot of the profile picture from the firebase database and cache it for offline use.

Comment: https://m.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLxefhmF0pcPlLVOWeYgwXDXpmns4UnyeR.                                           <br/>      here's the link to the tutorials I'm watching... You can skip to video 18 that's where I'm stuck at

Comment: I recommend you to use an image loading and caching library for Android, named [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide)

Comment: I tried Glide yet the picture's still not showing.

Comment: I've posted a screenshot of how my settings activity looks.The image is supposed to be on top of my username but its blank.Here's the link:https://ibb.co/n7n3f0

Comment: @AlexMamo please check out the screenshot

Comment: Please add the code that you are using.

Comment: https://github.com/LexSwitch/miChat-profile-picture-not-showing @AlexMamo

Comment: @AlexMamo help .

Comment: @LexSwitch Please make your question clear as also vatbub asked you.

Comment: The whole project is in the link I posted about on Github. When I come my profile picture in the settings activity it's supposed to be uploaded into my firebase database and the image should appear in the settings activity like all normal chat apps do but the part where the image is supposed to show in my settings activity remains blank through the image is uploaded into my firebase alright.